# WordPress search returning duplicate results

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a search box on a WordPress site I'm currently working on that is returning somewhat sporadic duplicate results based on the number of keywords entered into the search. For example, if I enter the keywords "Green Lake" into the box, it will return Post A twice, Post B twice, Post C once or twice. If I enter "Green Lake Lake" (three keywords), it will return Post A three times, Post B three times, Post C two or three times. Etc etc.

I think I've narrowed the issue down to the following code. Can anyone point out anything obvious? I think it has something to do with the foreach loop on $keywords, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['keywords'] ) && ! empty( $_REQUEST['keywords'] ) ) {

        $filter_posts = [];
        $keywords     = explode( ' ', strtolower( $_REQUEST['keywords'] ) );

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

            foreach ( $keywords as $keyword ) {

                // if the keyword is in the title the don't search the post content
                if (
                    strpos( strtolower( $post->post_title ), $keyword ) !== false
                    ||
                    strpos( strtolower( $post->post_content ), $keyword ) !== false
                ) {

                    $filter_posts[] = $post;

                }

            }

        }

        $posts = $filter_posts;

    }

    wp_send_json_success( json_encode( $posts ) );
```

Comment: Wordpress provide default search then why you create in this way? is there any specific reason ?